# css parent child

Tags: css

I have my form inside `<ul><li>` and working fine when using label and form elements.

The CSS for the form is simple: (no need to explain)

```
#form ul {....}
#form ul li {....}
```

My problem is that now, instead of drawing a form element, i want to draw a tree using `<ul><li>`

```
<li>  
    <label>Parent Category</label> 
    <div>

      // ... draw TREE here
    </div>
</li>
```

But my CSS looks like `#form ul li {....}`, which means that it will affect the `<ul><li>` that I have for the tree too.

If I use `#form ul>li {....}` to style only direct children, it doesn't work in IE6.

One solution here is to use `#tree ul li {}` to cancel out the styling that I don't need from the `#form ul>li {}`. But the `#tree ul li {}` is something that I will also use in places that don't need to cancel the `#form ul li {}` styles.

Is there any other solution I can apply, so `#form ul li` and `#tree ul li` are independent from each other?

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks

Comment: Your question really is unclear... You want to style 2 different UL's? Or do you want to style the first LI in the UL's? Or....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make 2 selectors:

```
#form ul li .tree ul li, .tree ul li {style here}
```

This way the first selector affects the #tree inside #form and second one will still work for any other tree wherever on the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
#form ul li div ul{---cancel styles---}
#form ul li div ul li{---cancel styles---}
```

Comment: Thats my implementation know, but i am looking for other solution

Answer (score 0):

if you're ok with leaving out IE 6, you can use CSS3 child combinators

```
#tree > ul >li {put your styles here}
```

these styles will apply only to the li which is a grand-child of #tree and not to the other li (which is a grand-child of #form)

hope this helps

Comment: in fact the `>` selector is CSS 2.1 or even 2.0. Still, doesn't work in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Put a class on your tree

```
<div id="tree" class="themed_tree"> ... </div>
```

and use the selector:

```
#tree.themed_tree ul li
```

Comment: its not working if parent #form ul li {} because #tree.themed_tree ul li is child of #form ul li.To work needs #form ul>li {} but this approach fails on IE6

Comment: Yes but you can fine tune this particular class (as removig the inherited values) witout modifying all your `#tree ul li` of the file.